# Ошибка при поиске наибольшего и наименьшего числа, суммы чисел

Tags: python

необходимо найти наибольшее , наименьшее число и посчитать среднее без учета наибольшего и наименьшего числа

с клавиатуры вводим 5 чисел через пробел

```
def itog(number):
number = input('Введите баллы')
number.split(' ')
a = number[0]
b = number[2]
c = number[4]
d = number[6]
e = number[8]
h = min(number)
k = max(number)

print(h)
print(k)

itog = ((a+b+c+d+e)-int(h)-int(k))/5
print(itog)

itog(number)
```

правильно считает максимальное число из введенных

почему не выводит минимальное?

почему выдает ошибку ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base ?

Comment: У вас itog то функция, то переменная. Разберитесь сначала с этим.

Answer (score 0):

Приведённый код работает со строками, а не числами, и минимум таки  печатает, только он незаметный - например, строка пустая.

Вот как можно ввести список чисел:

```
number = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(min(number))
print(max(number))
```

Comment: можете пояснить почему возникает пустая строка? попробовала с вашим кодом (ниже) тоже выдает ошибку max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: 'def itog(number):
    number = input('Введите баллы')
    numbers = map(int, number.split(' '))
    h = min(numbers)
    k = max(numbers)
    
    print(h)
    print(k)
    
    v = (sum(numbers)-h-k)/5
    print(v)
    
itog(number)'

Answer (score 0):

По моему нужно так

```
nlist = list(map(int, input().split()))
nmax=max(nlist)
nmin=min(nlist)
itog=(sum(nlist)-nmax-nmin)/(len(nlist)-2)
print('min:'+str(nmin)+' max:'+str(nmax)+' itog:'+str(itog))
```